# WCF Service Error MSVSMON.exe

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-data-services

I have tried to connect the wcf service with the windows application but i have faced the following issue,

Method:Void HandleReturnMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage)
Message:The caller was not authenticated by the service.

I have attached the image of that issue as well.

[image]

Comment: It seems like you are trying to remote debug the service.You should install Visual Studio Remote Debugger on the server PC to be able to do that.

Comment: The image says you are not running MSVSMON.EXE which is needed to debug remotely. Also, disable the firewall which sometimes doesn't allow to debug. Run the msvsmon.exe as an administrator user.